# Firebase Unity SDK: realtime database not working in editor in Unity 2019

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project using the Firebase SDK which works fine in Unity 2018, but after upgrading to 2019, it throws a WebSocketException when running in the editor and trying to access the realtime database. The same thing happens when I create a new project in Unity 2019 and try to use the realtime database. Is there a solution, or is this a bug?